# Mocking APIs for angular app component testing

Tags: angularjs, testing, mocking, httpbackend

Currently my team and I are facing an issue with our testing strategy.. We have our mocks set up in a completely inefficient way and need to find a better solution. Currently what we do is create a JSON file, often copied from the network traffic on the UI, and then in our component test we just use httpBackend and do a whenGET(jsonFileIWasTalkingAbout).

This is proving to be inefficient because we have to create a new JSON file, even if it is for the same API, to fit the test data needs of that component test.

What we are looking for is a more reusable solution, where we can pass in data to feed the API mock rather than what we are currently doing. Does anyone have a good mocking solution in place that they would like to brag about or any tools they have found that have worked? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think combination of stub and Fake XMLHTTPRequest from SinonJS should help you achieve what you need.

Comment: This is an interesting looking tool, however our component tests are seperate from unit tests. We actually treat our component tests like blackbox testing and compile a component, and run tests based around the compiled HTML we receive. I have never heard of XMLHTTPRequest.. I am not sure if thats what we are looking for.

Comment: XMLHTTPRequest (or XHR) is what AJAX uses behind the scene to make calls to API server without re-rendering DOM. XHR is base of AJAX revolution.

Comment: Was this answer helpful? Do you have follow up questions?